# Git: Checkout certain commit: "detached head" state

Tags: git, git-detached-head

I want to go back to a certain commit (not just one file; the whole project). I tried: `git checkout 0780033` but then I got the following message:

> You are in "detached head" state. You can look around...

And then I am not in actual Branch --> but in branch ((0780033...). I want to "copy" the project at this commit (0780033), to be the newest version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Revert Git repo to a previous commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-git-repo-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 2):

When you checkout to a specific commit, you change to **detached head** state that means that you aren't in your branch anymore.

You can create a new branch from your specific commit as @Mureinik explained with:

```
$ git checkout -b my_new_branch
```

And come back to your branch with:

```
$ git checkout previous_branch
```

If you want to know more about detached state, I'd suggest you to read the following links:

- http://gitolite.com/detached-head.html (explanation of detached state)
- https://git-scm.com/blog (explanation of the concept of HEAD and index)

Answer (score 0):

You could check out this commit to a new branch and work from there:

```
$ git checkout -b my_new_branch
```